# How to handle binary data in yii2?

Tags: activerecord, yii2, binary

I have a table that I created using

```
CREATE TABLE `digiid_callback` (  `nonce` BINARY(8) NOT NULL,  `address` BINARY(20),  `expire` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`nonce`) )
```

So it has 3 fields.  1 is a timestamp and the other 2 hold a small binary data filed.

I am new to working with the yii framework and was wondering what the proper way to create an ActiveRecord for this table would be.

Normally if I was trying to select data from a table like this I would use

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE nonce=UNHEX(?) LIMIT 1;`

the yii equivalent seems to be ObjectName::findOne(?);   but I don't know how to add the UNHEX which is needed.

Answer (score 0):

First create DB table, then generate ActiveRecord (AR) class for that table using [gii tool](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-gii) and then learn [AR tutorial](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record).